# ldaps query against dc from appliance

Tags: tls

recently I had to configure a feature called directory sync on our appliance to sync with our DC. The requirement was to run the sync over LDAPS. It works BUT what I'm wondering is, the DC's cert is issued by our internal CA, and the appliance has absolutely no knowledge about it (it's not domain joined, the root CA cert is not uploaded in to the appliance). Now I'm not sure whether this is the proper way to handle it, I mean a browser will notify you that something is "wrong" so I would assume that some sort of protection / warning mechanism should be in place on the appliance or am I worrying to much ?

thanks
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... am I worrying to much ?

Maybe not.
Unfortunately it is not uncommon that certificate validation is done improperly.  Many think that encryption is enough and that certificate validation is just an annoying thing with all this root CA hassle etc. In not so far away times for example PHP or Python did not check any certificates at all by default and this was only [fixed in PHP version 5.6 2](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php) and [python 2.7.9](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-9365) about 2 years ago. And for example most mail server simply ignore bad certificates too.

Thus it might well be that the unknown application you use does not check certificates properly. It might also be that you need to explicitly configure it to check certificates. When in doubt look at the documentation or contact the vendor.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just wondering why the SSL/TLS handshake is not taking care of the cert verification process by itself? Well, when looking at the handshake process I believe it does, at least I can see that the Server is sending it's certificate right after the ServerHello packet. Why didn't they implement a mechanism to verify that indeed that certificate was verified / trusted (to let the server know) . I hope you get the point of my question.

Comment: @adam86: the necessary information (the certificate) are sent during the SSL handshake. But the client application  must actually take the certificate and check if it is issued by a locally trusted CA and if the subject of the certificate matches the expected one. And this is where application often fail because in order to verify a certificate you must actually know which CA to trust.

Comment: Thank you Steffen. It makes much more sense now. I appropriate you expertise.